# Android Studio no devices show up in Device Selection but the AVD Manager is full of them

Tags: android, flutter, android-virtual-device

I'm using Flutter with Android Studio and the device selection on the menu does not show any devices listed meanwhile there are 3 devices in my AVD Manager. This is what the Device Selection looks like.

[image: Device Selection Dropdown]

Now this is a screenshot of my AVD Manager:

[image: AVD Manager]

My overall intention is to get these AVDs to show up in the Device Selection. What steps should I take in order to get this to happen?

Comment: check whether you have set up dart and flutter path correctly inside the android studio

Comment: I just reinstalled dart and flutter and they are both installed properly in Android Studio.