# Physical Mobile Device detected but not listed in Device Selection Spinner Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, usb-debugging, device-manager

I am currently learning flutter in Android Studio. Android Studio detects my physical device connected but does not list it in Device Selection spinner.
Below picture will elaborate my issue further:

[image: Android Physical Device Connection Issue Android Studio]

As can be seen, Mobile device is listed in Device Manager and in Connected Devices (RED Boxes right side) but in device selection box only Chrome & Windows appear.

I have googled and most close to my problem I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361982/android-studio-no-devices-show-up-in-device-selection-but-the-avd-manager-is-ful). But this did not help me to resolve my issue.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Edit**

I further checked and found following symptoms which to best of my knowldege can help to diagnose issue unluckily I myself could'nt figure out

1. My device manager instead of listing an Android Phone in devices list a USB Device for my Mobile Device (Pic as under)
   [image]
2. However, adb does recognises my device and reboots it when i input command`adb reboot` (pic attached)
   [image]

Comment: Check-in your device `USB Debugging ` is On or Off

Comment: @jcredking yes, it's ON.